# How can I open a popup html tabel window using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am working on an `HTML` table. I want that if 'Click here to show the popup' is clicked, a full-page pop should open with close icon/text, so the user can close the pop. I tried the above code, but unfortunately, it did not work. I added jquery too, but that did not work either.

I added the following code too, So when the “Open” and “Close” HTML buttons are clicked, jQuery needs to add or remove the “active” class.

```
$(".open").on("click", function(){
$(".popup, .popup-content").addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.englectureenglish {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
.trenglectureenglishtd th{text-align:center !important;}

.englectureenglishtdtr td, .trenglectureenglishtd th {
  border: 1px solid #424040;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

.englectureenglish {
  counter-reset: rowNumber;
  /*width: 30%;*/
  margin: auto;
}

.englectureenglish .englectureenglishtdtr {
  counter-increment: rowNumber;
}

.englectureenglish tr td:first-child::before {
  content: counter(rowNumber);
  min-width: 1em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}
th.sticky-header {
  position: sticky;
  top: -1px;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #8dbbea;
}

.hover_bkgr_fricc{
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    cursor:pointer;
    display:none;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    text-align:center;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index:10000;
}
.hover_bkgr_fricc .helper{
    display:inline-block;
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.hover_bkgr_fricc > div {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 60px #555;
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 551px;
    min-height: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 60%;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 15px 5%;
}
.popupCloseButton {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 3px solid #999;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    right: -20px;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
.popupCloseButton:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.trigger_popup_fricc {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">
<table class="englectureenglish">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="trenglectureenglishtd">
      <th class="sticky-header">SN</th>
      <th class="sticky-header">1111</th>
      <th class="sticky-header">2222</th>
      <th class="sticky-header">3333</th>
      <th class="sticky-header">4444</th>
      <th class="sticky-header">5555</th> 
    </tr>
    <tr class="englectureenglishtdtr">
      <td class="englectureenglishtd"></td>
      <td class="englectureenglishtd">aaaa</td>
      <td class="englectureenglishtd">bbbb</td>
      <td class="englectureenglishtd">cccc</td>
      <td class="englectureenglishtd">dddd</td>
      <td class="englectureenglishtd"><a class="wordssynonyms">Click here to show the popup</a>
        <table class="englectureenglish">
          <tbody>
            <tr class="trenglectureenglishtd">
              <th class="sticky-header">SN</th>
              <th class="sticky-header">1111</th>
              <th class="sticky-header">2222</th>
              <th class="sticky-header">3333</th>
              <th class="sticky-header">4444</th>
              <th class="sticky-header">5555</th> 
            </tr>
              <tr class="englectureenglishtdtr">
                <td class="englectureenglishtd"></td>
                <td class="englectureenglishtd">aaaa</td>
                <td class="englectureenglishtd">bbbb</td>
                <td class="englectureenglishtd">cccc</td>
                <td class="englectureenglishtd">dddd</td>
                <td class="englectureenglishtd">eeee</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I want to open pop up like this webaite  https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/admit

When 'See examples for synonyms' link is clicked, a new popup opens. I want to make similar.

Comment: Its not clear what you are trying to do - where is the popup in your HTML - do you want to open a second table in a pop modal ?

Comment: Hello, I have added the question.

Comment: What the site that you describe does is modify the existing element with a position fixed. This however does modify the size of the container of your element since your moving the content to a different z-index. So unless you refocus your element you might be better of just duplicating it because in mobile it would otherwise a pain to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply make a custom `popup` like that website using `CSS` and add some `color` and make it `position:` `fixed` with `height` as `100%`

I have added a close `X` button as well which will remove the class active from your `popup`.

When you `click` on `Click here to show the popup` we will add class `active` to our popup.

**Live Demo:**

```js
//Open popup
$(".wordssynonyms").on("click", function() {
  $('.center').addClass('active');
});

//Close popup
$("#close").on("click", function() {
  $('.center').removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.englectureenglish {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.trenglectureenglishtd th {
  text-align: center !important;
}

.englectureenglishtdtr td,
.trenglectureenglishtd th {
  border: 1px solid #424040;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

.englectureenglish {
  counter-reset: rowNumber;
  /*width: 30%;*/
  margin: auto;
}

.englectureenglish .englectureenglishtdtr {
  counter-increment: rowNumber;
}

.englectureenglish tr td:first-child::before {
  content: counter(rowNumber);
  min-width: 1em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}

th.sticky-header {
  position: sticky;
  top: -1px;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #8dbbea;
}

.hover_bkgr_fricc {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10000;
}

.hover_bkgr_fricc .helper {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.hover_bkgr_fricc>div {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 60px #555;
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 551px;
  min-height: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 60%;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 15px 5%;
}

.popupCloseButton {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #999;
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  right: -20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.popupCloseButton:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.trigger_popup_fricc {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.center {
  margin: auto;
  width: 70%;
  padding: 1em;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  position: fixed;
  left: 15%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: white;
  height: 100%;
}

#close {
  float: right;
}

.hideform {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}

.wordssynonyms {
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">
  <table class="englectureenglish">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="trenglectureenglishtd">
        <th class="sticky-header">SN</th>
        <th class="sticky-header">1111</th>
        <th class="sticky-header">2222</th>
        <th class="sticky-header">3333</th>
        <th class="sticky-header">4444</th>
        <th class="sticky-header">5555</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="englectureenglishtdtr">
        <td class="englectureenglishtd"></td>
        <td class="englectureenglishtd">aaaa</td>
        <td class="englectureenglishtd">bbbb</td>
        <td class="englectureenglishtd">cccc</td>
        <td class="englectureenglishtd">dddd</td>
        <td class="englectureenglishtd"><a class="wordssynonyms" title="Click me open pop">Click here to show the popup</a>
          <table class="englectureenglish">
            <tbody>
              <tr class="trenglectureenglishtd">
                <th class="sticky-header">SN</th>
                <th class="sticky-header">1111</th>
                <th class="sticky-header">2222</th>
                <th class="sticky-header">3333</th>
                <th class="sticky-header">4444</th>
                <th class="sticky-header">5555</th>
              </tr>
              <tr class="englectureenglishtdtr">
                <td class="englectureenglishtd"></td>
                <td class="englectureenglishtd">aaaa</td>
                <td class="englectureenglishtd">bbbb</td>
                <td class="englectureenglishtd">cccc</td>
                <td class="englectureenglishtd">dddd</td>
                <td class="englectureenglishtd">eeee</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <div class="center hideform">
    <button id="close" title="Click me to close">X</button> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley
    of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
    Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to hide table that is showing after 'Click here to show the popup ' and display in popup when 'Click here to show the popup' is clicked.

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again. When more than one data is added, the close button does not work. Here is the code https://pastebin.com/ZnLSQ6is

Comment: @Karan Okay sure. If there are multiple popups and close buttons then we need to use a `class` selector not `id` : here is a working js fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/nmpgs72o/ - Happy coding